# Edit Mail rules manually

Tags: bash, plist, spam, apple-mail

I want to edit manually the following .plist file:

```
/Users/<myname>/Library/Mail/V5/MailData/SyncedRules.plist
```

Because I get a lot of spam and adding each spammer address to the rules using Mail is impraticable:

[image]

and there are many addres to be added. Since I know a bit bash scripting, sed and awk I'm thinking to write a script that automatically adds the addresses from selected email to the plist file above.

[image]

---

#### So, what is my question?

In conclusion, for each spammer addres the script should add a new `dict` entry with following fields:

```
        <dict>
            <key>CriterionUniqueId</key>
            <string>CC4CB669-0D44-4A32-80B1-02D069718304</string> (*)
            <key>Expression</key>
            <string>spammer@address.spam</string>
            <key>Header</key>
            <string>From</string>
        </dict>
```

How the string at (*) is generated? How can I fill it?

Comment: That's a unique ID generated internally by Mail. I'm not sure if there's a way for you to do it yourself. Have you considered using AppleScript or Automator to automate this through the Mail application, rather than editing the file directly?

Comment: You could just try generating a bunch of random hex numbers with the same lengths as that example. The chance that you'll get a conflict is negligible.

Comment: If you are saying that this value is purely random, it is very easy generating new ones paying attention to avoid conflicts. My question is that value is merely random or generated with some criteria?

Comment: I don't know the actual algorithm (I tried searching for it, but can't find it), it probably involves hashing a timestamp or something like that. But all that probably matters is that they're unique.

Answer (score 0):

Type `uuidgen` in the terminal.

Uuidgen will create a unique identifier that can be tagged with, in this case, email; But also many various devices etc. Anyhow, I'm going to try that out myself as well, I needed to manually modify the rules.